# Can only access Web Service namespace through User Controls, not plain C# classesm, in Silverlight

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, web-services

I'm not sure why I'm having this problem, but I can only talk to my web service through a User Control or App.xaml.cs.  I'm trying to use the service in a simple data oriented class so I didn't want to use a User Control.

This compiles fine:

```
//App.xaml.cs
<using statements...>

namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    public partial class App : Application
    {
       private SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
           = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient();

        public App()
        {
            this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
            this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

            InitializeComponent();
....
```

This does not:

```
//Controller.cs
<using statements copied from App.xml.cs...>

namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    private SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
       = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient();

    public class Controller
    {

    }
}
```

Visual Studio reports "Expected class, delegate, enum..." for any reference to SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient.

I'm using the same steps listed here:

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Consuming-ASMX-Web-Services-with-Silverlight-2.aspx

My web service's namespace is Sharepoint_Integration_Project.SharepointWS and I've tried fully qualifying it and that hasn't helped.

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: off topic - this was a simple typographical error - and won't be helpful to future SO users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a field declaration outside of the class declaration.  Can't do that.

Change:

```
namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    private SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
       = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient();

    public class Controller
    {

    }
}
```

to:

```
namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    public class Controller
    {
       private SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
          = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have fields/functions/anything other than class/struct outside of classes/structs:

```
namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    private SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
       = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient(); // outside of class
}
```

If you it to be global, you can use static class: (and to be usable you should probably remove prive)

```
namespace Sharepoint_Integration_Project
{
    static class Name
    {
        private static SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient SpWSSoap 
           = new SharepointWS.SharepointWebServiceSoapClient(); // inside of class
    }
}
```